# mPDF - Dividing one table cell into two pages

Tags: html-table, paging, mpdf

In a PDF which is generated by mPDF, I would like to divide a table cell into two (or more) pages.
The cell contains very long text, so its font size is forced small.
However, I want to avoid small text.

Comment: (Note that mPDF will always resize tables if it is the only way to fit a row or whole table onto a full page.) https://mpdf.github.io/tables/tables.html

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$html = '
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
p { margin: 0pt; }
table.items {
    border: 0.1mm solid #000000;
}
td { vertical-align: top; }
.items td {
    border-left: 0.1mm solid #000000;
    border-right: 0.1mm solid #000000;
}
table thead td { background-color: #EEEEEE;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0.1mm solid #000000;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
.items td.blanktotal {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    border: 0.1mm solid #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 0mm none #000000;
    border-top: 0.1mm solid #000000;
    border-right: 0.1mm solid #000000;
}
.items td.totals {
    text-align: right;
    border: 0.1mm solid #000000;
}
.items td.cost {
    text-align: "." center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!--mpdf
<htmlpageheader name="myheader">
<table width="100%"><tr>
<td width="50%" style="color:#0000BB; "><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14pt;">Acme Trading Co.</span><br />123 Anystreet<br />Your City<br />GD12 4LP<br /><span style="font-family:dejavusanscondensed;">&#9742;</span> 01777 123 567</td>
<td width="50%" style="text-align: right;">Invoice No.<br /><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12pt;">0012345</span></td>
</tr></table>
</htmlpageheader>
<htmlpagefooter name="myfooter">
<div style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; font-size: 9pt; text-align: center; padding-top: 3mm; ">
Page {PAGENO} of {nb}
</div>
</htmlpagefooter>
<sethtmlpageheader name="myheader" value="on" show-this-page="1" />
<sethtmlpagefooter name="myfooter" value="on" />
mpdf-->
<div style="text-align: right">Date: 13th November 2008</div>
<table width="100%" style="font-family: serif;" cellpadding="10"><tr>
<td width="45%" style="border: 0.1mm solid #888888; "><span style="font-size: 7pt; color: #555555; font-family: sans;">SOLD TO:</span><br /><br />345 Anotherstreet<br />Little Village<br />Their City<br />CB22 6SO</td>
<td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="45%" style="border: 0.1mm solid #888888;"><span style="font-size: 7pt; color: #555555; font-family: sans;">SHIP TO:</span><br /><br />345 Anotherstreet<br />Little Village<br />Their City<br />CB22 6SO</td>
</tr></table>
<br />
<table class="items" width="100%" style="font-size: 9pt; border-collapse: collapse; " cellpadding="8">
<thead>
<tr>
<td width="15%">Ref. No.</td>
<td width="10%">Quantity</td>
<td width="45%">Description</td>
<td width="15%">Unit Price</td>
<td width="15%">Amount</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<!-- ITEMS HERE -->
<tr>
<td align="center">MF1234567</td>
<td align="center">10</td>
<td>Large pack Hoover bags</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;2.56</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;25.60</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">MX37801982</td>
<td align="center">1</td>
<td>Womans waterproof jacket<br />Options - Red and charcoal.</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;102.11</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;102.11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">MR7009298</td>
<td align="center">25</td>
<td>Steel nails; oval head; 30mm x 3mm. Packs of 1000.</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;12.26</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;325.60</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">MF1234567</td>
<td align="center">10</td>
<td>Large pack Hoover bags</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;2.56</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;25.60</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">MX37801982</td>
<td align="center">1</td>
<td>Womans waterproof jacket<br />Options - Red and charcoal.</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;102.11</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;102.11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">MR7009298</td>
<td align="center">25</td>
<td>Steel nails; oval head; 30mm x 3mm. Packs of 1000.</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;12.26</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;325.60</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">MF1234567</td>
<td align="center">10</td>
<td>Large pack Hoover bags</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;2.56</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;25.60</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">MX37801982</td>
<td align="center">1</td>
<td>Womans waterproof jacket<br />Options - Red and charcoal.</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;102.11</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;102.11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">MR7009298</td>
<td align="center">25</td>
<td>Steel nails; oval head; 30mm x 3mm. Packs of 1000.</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;12.26</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;325.60</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">MF1234567</td>
<td align="center">10</td>
<td>Large pack Hoover bags</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;2.56</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;25.60</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">MX37801982</td>
<td align="center">1</td>
<td>Womans waterproof jacket<br />Options - Red and charcoal.</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;102.11</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;102.11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">MR7009298</td>
<td align="center">25</td>
<td>Steel nails; oval head; 30mm x 3mm. Packs of 1000.</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;12.26</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;325.60</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">MF1234567</td>
<td align="center">10</td>
<td>Large pack Hoover bags</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;2.56</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;25.60</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">MX37801982</td>
<td align="center">1</td>
<td>Womans waterproof jacket<br />Options - Red and charcoal.</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;102.11</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;102.11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">MF1234567</td>
<td align="center">10</td>
<td>Large pack Hoover bags</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;2.56</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;25.60</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">MX37801982</td>
<td align="center">1</td>
<td>Womans waterproof jacket<br />Options - Red and charcoal.</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;102.11</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;102.11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">MR7009298</td>
<td align="center">25</td>
<td>Steel nails; oval head; 30mm x 3mm. Packs of 1000.</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;12.26</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;325.60</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">MR7009298</td>
<td align="center">25</td>
<td>Steel nails; oval head; 30mm x 3mm. Packs of 1000.</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;12.26</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;325.60</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">MF1234567</td>
<td align="center">10</td>
<td>Large pack Hoover bags</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;2.56</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;25.60</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">MX37801982</td>
<td align="center">1</td>
<td>Womans waterproof jacket<br />Options - Red and charcoal.</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;102.11</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;102.11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">MR7009298</td>
<td align="center">25</td>
<td>Steel nails; oval head; 30mm x 3mm. Packs of 1000.</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;12.26</td>
<td class="cost">&pound;325.60</td>
</tr>
<!-- END ITEMS HERE -->
<tr>
<td class="blanktotal" colspan="3" rowspan="6"></td>
<td class="totals">Subtotal:</td>
<td class="totals cost">&pound;1825.60</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="totals">Tax:</td>
<td class="totals cost">&pound;18.25</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="totals">Shipping:</td>
<td class="totals cost">&pound;42.56</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="totals"><b>TOTAL:</b></td>
<td class="totals cost"><b>&pound;1882.56</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="totals">Deposit:</td>
<td class="totals cost">&pound;100.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="totals"><b>Balance due:</b></td>
<td class="totals cost"><b>&pound;1782.56</b></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div style="text-align: center; font-style: italic;">Payment terms: payment due in 30 days</div>
</body>
</html>
';

require_once __DIR__ . '/bootstrap.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'margin_left' => 20,
    'margin_right' => 15,
    'margin_top' => 48,
    'margin_bottom' => 25,
    'margin_header' => 10,
    'margin_footer' => 10
]);

$mpdf->SetProtection(array('print'));
$mpdf->SetTitle("Acme Trading Co. - Invoice");
$mpdf->SetAuthor("Acme Trading Co.");
$mpdf->SetWatermarkText("Paid");
$mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;
$mpdf->watermark_font = 'DejaVuSansCondensed';
$mpdf->watermarkTextAlpha = 0.1;
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: So, what does this piece of PHP code do? Does it solve any problem? or does it cause problems?

Comment: @Luuk is a good workaround